# Run .sh script instead of an executable

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

[image]How can I run an .sh file in eclipse instead of an executable?

I need to start the executable with a special command. My sh file would look like this `optirun ./executable`

Comment: Is the sh file executable, `chmod +x file.sh` ?

Comment: yes it is. I told eclipse to use this file instead of the executable but nothing happens then. If I double click the .sh file it works just fine.

Comment: did you tried it with the absolute path?

Comment: yes I am using the absolute path. :/

Comment: Added a screenshot of my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it by passing shell with the script example:  `optirun sh ./executable`

Comment: You mean I should add `optirun sh ./executable` in the .sh file itself? I tried it and it didn't work either. I added a screenshot of my configuration.

Comment: @MaikKlein No, what Travis G is saying is that your line should not say `file.sh` but `sh ./file.sh` - the reason for this is that the IDE will `exec()` the file, not call the shell to execute it. So you need to run the shell itself, with arguments.